# Is there a pnpm CLI equivalent to "yarn workspace"?

Tags: node.js, yarn-workspaces, pnpm

I'm trying https://pnpm.io/ with workspaces and I can't seem to be able to install packages and run commands in specific workspaces as I do with Yarn.

Using yarn, I could do, for example:

```sh
# adds express to the server workspace
yarn workspace server add express

# run the build script in the common workspace
yarn workspace common run build
```

How do I achieve the same with the pnpm CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see https://pnpm.io/filtering

```sh
# adds express to the server workspace
pnpm --filter server add express

# run the build script in the common workspace
pnpm --filter common run build
```

Instead of `--filter` you may also use `-F`.

Comment: Oh wow that was not intuitive at all. Thank you very much. Stay strong in Ukraine!